# rc.local contents not running on startup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I have a rc.local file that contains the follow to run concourse ci on startup

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

sudo ./concourse web --basic-auth-username myuser --basic-auth-password 
mypass --session-signing-key session_signing_key --tsa-host-key tsa_host_key      
--tsa-authorized-keys authorized_worker_keys --external-url http://127.0.0.1   
--postgres-data-source postgres://ubuntu:ubuntu@localhost/atc &>     
/home/ubuntu/concourse-web.log&

sudo ./concourse worker   --work-dir /opt/concourse/worker   --tsa-host 
127.0.0.1   --tsa-public-key tsa_host_key.pub   --tsa-worker-private-key 
worker_key &> /home/ubuntu/concourse-worker.log&
```

when the machine starts concourse is not running.

When I execute the rc.local manually doing /etc/rc.local it runs and I can close my session and it keeps running.

where am i going wrong?

Comment: irrelevant but try appending to your log file. change `>` to `>>`

Comment: yeah done that but no change

Comment: sudo ./concourse  looks like a relative path. which may not be know at system start.  you might try and explicit path.

Comment: You are right, I knew I was doing something daft, it was a relative path which was working when I ran rc.local from my home directory. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if your /etc/rc.local file has +x execution permission. Basically you could issue a chmod 755 /etc/rc.local. Also do a update-rc.d rc.local defaults and reboot. See if that helps